# How to pass PointMode into Canvas.drawPoints(..) in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am calling the function `drawPoints` as below, which follows the [API-doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawPoints.html)

```
      final paint = new Paint()
       ..color = Colors.blue[400]
       ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
     var offsetList = [new Offset(2.0, 5.0), new Offset(50.0, 100.0)];
     canvas.drawPoints(const PointMode(1), offsetList, paint);
```

When I pass in `const PointMode(1)` into the `canvas.drawPoints`, it throws compiler error. What is the correct way to passing `PointMode` into this function?

Comment: Can you please edit you question to include a whole class as a working example which can be run on a mobile device? At least the build method with all its dependencies would be helpful to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PointMode is an enum, you can not instantiate it. You can check all the available PointModes from [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/PointMode-class.html).

To specify PointMode in drawPoints method, you can just change

```
canvas.drawPoints(const PointMode(1), offsetList, paint);
```

to

```
canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, offsetList, paint);
```

Comment: actually I tried several ways including what you mentioned, for some reason `PointMode` is undefined, so I get the red line under it.. which throws complier error.

Answer (score 5):

It's correct to use

canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, offsetList, paint);

but for the definition you must import 'dart:ui'.

Answer (score 4):

As [Alessio Ricci said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484510/3681880), you need to import `dart:ui`. Here is a fuller answer to see everything in context.

## How to draw points in Flutter

[image]

To paint in Flutter you use the [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget. The `CustomPaint` widget takes a [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) object as a parameter. In that class you have to override the `paint` method, which gives you a canvas that you can paint on. Here is the code to draw the points in the image above.

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final pointMode = ui.PointMode.points;
  final points = [
    Offset(50, 100),
    Offset(150, 75),
    Offset(250, 250),
    Offset(130, 200),
    Offset(270, 100),
  ];
  final paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeWidth = 4
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
  canvas.drawPoints(pointMode, points, paint);
}
```

Notes:

- When using low level methods from `dart:ui` it is a common practice to prefix the classes with `ui.`.
- You should stay within the bounds of size.
- An Offset is a pair of (dx, dy) doubles, offset from the top left corner, which is (0, 0).
- If you don’t set the color, the default is white.

#### Other options

You can connect the points if you use the `PointMode.polygon` option.

[image]

Using the `PointMode.lines` option only accepts pairs of lines. Notice that the last point is discarded.

[image]

#### Context

Here is the *main.dart* code so that you can see it in context. Note the `'dart:ui' as ui` import.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: HomeWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CustomPaint( //                       <-- CustomPaint widget
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: MyPainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter { //         <-- CustomPainter class
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //                                             <-- Insert your painting code here.
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

#### See also

See [this article](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10) for my fuller answer about `CustomPaint`.